# `android.support` cannot mix different versions

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have following dependencies in my android studio project.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:${kotlin_version}"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

I just added `com.google.android.gms:play-services` and I can't figure out why the following error is occuring:

```
All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 28.0.0, 25.2.0. ...
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem. I assume it has got to do with the play services dependency using a different versions of `android.support`, or something similar, but can't find a single solution on the internet.

P.S I'm using kotlin if that makes any difference

Comment: move your dependencies to `Androidx`

Comment: `com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0` is very old. Try to use something newer. Also it's not a good practice to use whole `play-service` bundle. Use specific module dependency like `location` or `analytics`.

Comment: @hfarhanahmed I've never heard of that, I'm new to app development

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman Ok thanks I'll try that

Comment: `android.support` is no longer supported by google and all support libraries are moved to `androidx` update your dependencies and you will be good. here is a guide by Google https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman Thanks that fixed the problem. I now have another problem, `android.support` and `androidx` cannot be combined.

Comment: @hfarhanahmed I will take a look at the migration guide thanks

Comment: Then you should migrate your project to AndroidX. In android studio follow: **Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX** and press **do Refactor**

Comment: got everything to work thanks a million :)